# Lee Smooth Manifolds Proposition 2.15 - What is a product of diffeomorphisms?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

In Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* 2nd Edition, item (b) of Proposition 2.15 reads as follows:

> Every finite product of diffeomorphisms between smooth manifolds is a diffeomorphism.

What exactly does he mean by "finite product of diffeomorphisms"?

Comment: I guess that if $f : M_1 \rightarrow N_1$ and $g : M_2 \rightarrow N_2$ are diffeos, it would be the natural $f \times g : M_1 \times M_2 \rightarrow N_1 \times N_2$. Does it make sense ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Makes sense to me, thanks :)

Comment: The definition of product map is on page 603 (same as TheSilverDoe's comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_i:M_i\to N_i$  denotes a map of smooth manifolds for $i=1,\ldots, k$, then as stated above, the product map $f_1\times\cdots\times f_k:\prod_i M_i\to \prod_i N_i$ is defined by $(f_1\times\cdots\times f_k)(x_1,\ldots, x_k)=(f(x_1),\ldots, f(x_k))$.

Indeed, the product of finitely many manifolds is again a manifold, so everything here makes sense.